# Many different sharded counters in single transaction

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have to increment three different counters in a single transaction. Beside that I have to manipulate three other entities as well. I get

```
too many entity groups in a single transaction
```

I've used the recipie from https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters to implement my counters. I increment my counters inside some model (class) methods depending on business logic.

As a workaround I implemented a deferred increment method that uses tasks to update the counter. But that doesn't scale well if the number of counters increases further as there is a limit of tasks in a single transaction as well (I thinks it's 5) and I guess it's not the most effective way.

I also found https://github.com/DocSavage/sharded_counter/blob/master/counter.py which seems to ensure updating the counter even in case of a db error through memcache. But I don't want to increment my counters if the transaction fails.

Another idea is to remember the counters I have to increment during a web request and to increment them in a single deferred task. I don't know how to implement this in a clean and thread safe way without passing objects created in the request to the model methods. I think this code would be ugly and not in the same transcation:

```
def my_request_handler():
    counter_session = model.counter_session()
    model.mylogic(counter_session, other_params)
    counter_session.write()
```

Any experiences or ideas?

BTW: I'm using python, ndb and flask
It would be ok if the counter is not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

As said in [Transactions and entity groups](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Transactions_and_entity_groups):

> the simplest approach is to determine which entities you need to be
>   able to process in the same transaction. Then, when you create those
>   entities, place them in the same entity group by declaring them with a
>   common ancestor. They will then all be in the same entity group and
>   you will always be able to update and read them transactionally.

Comment: This should probably be a comment instead of an answer